# "ModuleNotFoundError", How to fix it?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(receiver, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(User=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(receiver, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.Profile.save()
```

## apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'
    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

## Error in server

> File "C:\Users\Mian.G\Desktop\django_admin\users\apps.py", line 7, in
>   ready
>       import users.signals ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users.signals'

Comment: do you have a file called signals in the app `user`?

Comment: which django version you are using

Comment: Please see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) on how you should configure signal listeners.

Comment: yes i have a file @NakulNarayanan

Comment: please paste your project directory structure

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already solved this, as I see the post is almost 2 months old. But just in case you haven't.....is it possible you have created the 'signals.py' file in the 'users' sub directory instead of the 'users' root directory? I know from your code snippet that I am following the same tutorial and I was getting the same error because I hadn't created the 'signals.py' file in the 'users' app directory, but rather in the 'users' sub directory. If your 'signals.py' file is in the 'users' folder containing only 4 HTML files (login, logout, profile, register) then it is in the wrong location. Move it to the 'users' app directory and problem solved.